# how do I test httpOnly cookie flag

Tags: websphere, session-cookies, httponly

I have set the following property in websphere for the jsession cookie
    `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.HTTPOnlyCookies`.

Any idea how best to test this using JavaScript in Firefox or IE?

Answer (score 13):

It's a pain in IE. I have IE9 so your screens may be different.

Press F12, go to the network tab, and then press Start Capturing. Back in IE then open the page you want to view. Back in the F12 window you show see all the individual HTTP requests, select the one that's the page or asset you're checking the cookies on and double click on it. You should then be able to see all the response headers and cookies on their relevant tabs.

---

**Edit:**

A HttpOnly Cookie would look something like this:

Set-Cookie: SessionId=z5ymkk45aworjo2l31tlhqqv; path=/; **HttpOnly**

The cookie may not be sent with every response, so you may need to clear all of your cookies and then try again to make sure one is sent with the request you're monitoring.

Comment: It isn't showing the httponly nor the secure flag set on site, which has HTTPS enabled...

Answer (score 8):

Firebug - click on the Cookies tab

Answer (score 3):

firecookie for firefox gives me the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it on Chrome or Firefox is as below:

- Open the page for instance `somedomain.com`
- Open `dev` tools by right clicking on page and then clicking on `Inspect` or `Inspect Element`
- Click on `Network` tab
- Click on any of the actual request and go to `Headers` section
- Now look for `set-cookie` in `response headers`

Here is the screenshot for details
[image]

Answer (score -4):

add the following lines to your app
String

```
sessionid = request.getSession().getId();
response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid + "; secure; HttpOnly");
```