# Insecure HTTP cookies

Tags: http, cookies, cookie-httponly

Morning good people.

I have question related to HTTP Cookies, there is a way or tools that we can know our cookies have flag(s) Secure, HttpOnly?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I test httpOnly cookie flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316539/how-do-i-test-httponly-cookie-flag)

Answer (score 1):

Access your website from a any browser.Am giving an example from Firefox, press F12. goto Storage>Cookies>select cookie. If you click the cookie on right side, it will dislay the Data. Here you can see the Secure, HttpOnly flags.